# Сохранение изменений Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, nancy

Необходимо отслеживать изменения Entity (под entity я подразумеваю некий объект, с которым взаимодействует клиент через апи).

Пример задачи:

- Клиент имеет Api.dll, через которую взаимодействует с сервером. В данном апи реализованы статические методы (операции) с объектами.

Пример:

```
IOrder GetOrderById(Guid orderId) //делает Get запрос на сервер и возвращает IOrder по его Guid

bool AddGuest(IOrder order) //добавляет гостя к заказу
```

- В конечном счёте, после каких-либо изменений, необходимо вызвать метод `void SubmitChanges(ICredentials credentials)`, который сохраняет изменения на сервере в кэше (`ICredentials` - хранит в себе Guid клиента и некоторые его характеристики, которые нужны для сервера)

Операции по взаимодействию с Entity (пример - `AddGuest`) сохраняет изменения во **временный** кэш, который после вызова `SubmitChanges` переносит их из временного кэша в настоящий.

Вроде-бы, всё классно. Если клиенту не нужно сохранять изменения - он просто этого не делает. Сервер меньше напрягается и на него летит меньше запросов. Но проблема, которая стоит - что, если несколько клиентов будут редактировать одновременно один, например, IOrder? И те, и другие изменения будут сохраняться во временном кэше, заменяя друг друга. Как можно было-бы блокировать изменения с нескольких клиентов одновременно одной сущности до её сохранения в конечном кэше? Может добавить в `IOrder` свойство `Version`, которое-бы изменялось после каждой операции с сущностью? Метаюсь между тем, как это правильнее сделать, а не через какие-нибудь костыли.

P.S. Заранее ответ на вопрос, почему-бы не делать изменения на клиенте и потом сохранять конкретный заказ на сервере, например, создав метод `SubmitChanges(IOrder order, ICredentials credentials)`? Дело в том, что на клиенте пользователь может унаследоваться от IOrder, создав свой класс Order, поменять всё на свете и закинуть это на сервер. Именно из-за этого была придумана реализация через временный кэш.

P.S.S. После вызова `SubmitChanges` временный кэш очищается

P.S.S.S. Для чего нужен кэш - чтобы избежать постоянных запросов в базу данных. После некоторых действий кэш из `ConcurrentObservableDictionary` попадает окончательно в базу данных

Кэш хранится в следующем формате:

```
ConcurrentObservableDictionary<Guid, IOrder> _orders; //кэш

Dictionary<Guid, IOrder> _tempOrders; //временный кэш
```

Comment: У каждого клиента свой кэш. Как они могут заменять что-то у других?

Comment: Всего существует два подхода: пессимистичная блокировка и оптимистичная блокировка. От пессимистичной давно все отказались. Примеров обоих подходов полно. В том числе и с использованием Entity Framework.

Comment: `SubmitChanges` - это собственный метод? Меня терзают смутные подозрения по поводу использования древнего LINQ to SQL.

Comment: На клиенте используется EF? Если да, то кэш в него уже встроен под названием change tracking.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 1. Кэш общий и он хранится на сервере, который сделал на asp.net. Запросы с клиента на сервер и обратно идут по Http в формате json и потом десериализуются в классы, описанные в Api. Почему сделано именно так - для того, чтобы поддержать максимальную модульность и кроссплатформенность. Подключив Api.dll можно с лёгкость создать свой проект, который будет, используя методы из апи, взаимодействовать с сервером, посредством http запросов. 2. Не слышал ничего об этих блокировках. Обязательно почитаю сейчас. 3. SubmitChanges - собственный метод, который берёт изменения из....

Comment: ...временного кэша и добавляет/заменяет значения соответствующие Guid в основном кэше. 3.2 Я практически не взаимодействую с базой. При запуске сервера данные из бд попадают в кэш и там изменяются. В базу данных попадают значения из кэша только при закрытии кассовой смены, которая закрывается обычно в конце рабочего дня. 4. На сервере используется EF. Касаемо того, как происходит взаимодействие бд и кэша описал выше в 3.2

Comment: Грубо говоря, мне нужно запретить одновременно редактировать один объект нескольким клиентам, пока не будет выполнен метод сохранения (`SubmitChanges`), но, как я понял, для решения данной проблемы, стоит почитать про "оптимистичную блокировку". Не совсем понятно, укладывается ли данный подход под те условия, что данные для взаимодействия у меня хранятся в кэше, а не в бд, но постараюсь погуглить про это. Если сможете что-нибудь ещё подсказать, исходя из той информации, что я написал выше - буду благодарен

Comment: Насколько я понял, основная концепция состоит в том, чтобы присуждать какой-либо операции некую версию. Таким образом, если клиент, допустим, выполнил 3 операции, то в его классе, который он отправил на клиент, будет версия на 3 больше, чем в кэше. Я правильно понял? Если так, то я пытался применить подобный подход. Тем не менее, это не решает проблему запрета одновременного редактирования. Почему несколько клиентов не могут одновременно редактировать один объект? Почему клиент не может создать на своей стороне экземпляр класса, отредактировать, как ему нужно, и отправить на сервер?

Comment: В целом понятно. / Если сервак упадёт (баг в коде или электричество отключится), то данные из кэша пропадут. Нехорошо. / Всё уже придумано до нас: [Caching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Про блокировку. Один клиент считал сущность, начал работать с ней. Другой клиент считал сущность, начал работать с ней. Затем один из них сохраняет её. Когда другой попытается сохранить, получит отказ (исключение). И ему должно быть выведено сообщение, что сущность уже изменена. И показаны изменённые данные. Клиент должен выбрать: перезаписать их своими или отказаться от своей редактуры.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А, примерно, понял. Ну, у меня были похожие мысли. Постараюсь сейчас что-нибудь придумать с тем, как корректнее контролировать версии сущностей, чтобы не прошляпаться нигде. Касаемо отключения света и тд - думал об этом, но так и не решил, что делать с данной проблемой. Чуть позже обязательно прочитаю статья по вашей ссылке. Если есть желание - можете оформить в виде ответа - тыкну галочку. Думаю, дальше сам разберусь. Спасибо, ещё раз

Comment: [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency). И по ссылкам там смотрите Concurrency Tokens и пример проекта.